# Sending data between two raspberry pi's using bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

So far I've been able to connect two raspberry pi's through bluetooth using bluetoothctl. 
However, I'm stuck on how to send and receive data between them in realtime now that they're connected.

edit:
Things I've tried:

```
 sudo rfcomm bind 0 (insert address)
```

If I'm correct this should bind the bluetooth address to the /dev/rfcomm0
I did this for both RPI's and ran a write from one end and a read from the other end.

```
import serial

btSerial = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0", baudrate=9600, timeout=100)

while True:
        rcv = btSerial.read(512)
        print(rcv)
```

Sending end:

```
import serial
import time

print('x')
btSerial = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)
i = 0
print('started')


while True:
    btSerial.write("OK!")
    i = i + 1
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here is error from sending end:

```
x
started
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testBT.py", line 11, in <module>
    btSerial.write("OK!")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 489, in write
    raise SerialException('write failed: %s' % (v,))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Error from reading end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    rcv = btSerial.read(512)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 460, in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)
```

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Did you try to `encode` your string to `bytes`? Thus `btSerial.write("OK!".encode())` or `btSerial.write(b"OK!")`

Comment: Same error still comes up